# XML::RSS::Parser and Facebook RSS feed ...

Tags: xml, facebook, perl, rss, feedparser

I need a subroutine which should parse "any" RSS feed passed to it. I was using XML::RSS:Parser a few times already for some RSS feed but it does not work with Facebook.

Example code:

```
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::RSS::Parser;

my $url = join '', @ARGV;
die "No URL passed" if !$url;

# facebook does not accept default LWP user agent
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(agent => 'iGoogleBot');
my $res = $ua->get($url);
my $content = $res->decoded_content;

my $parser = XML::RSS::Parser->new;
my $feed = $parser->parse_string($content) or die $parser->errstr;
print "COUNT: ".$feed->item_count."\n";
```

Result with Wired Facebook Feed

```
xf@serv:/tmp$ ./rss.pl 'https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=19440638720&format=atom10'
Can't call method "contents" on an undefined value at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/XML/RSS/Parser.pm line 122.
```

I think that XML::RSS::Parsers does not get correct namespace from the root element and nothing works after that. Ideas how to solve this?

I could use XML::Simple or something similar to parse Facebook's RSS but I want one parser for all rss feeds.

I am going to hack around XML/RSS/Parser.pm to find the reason but it's not the solution to change package only for facebook. And this facebook feed works well in i.e. android rss reader.

Comment: Surely you can change the useragent name without implying that you have something to do with Google?

Comment: that was just for testing code. thanks for contribution to my question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you're getting a valid web feed back? You should probably check `$res->is_error` before trying to parse the content that you get back. When I just tried your code, I got a 500 error.

Also, you're asking for an Atom feed (`&format=atom10`). Are you sure that you want to parse that with an RSS parser? I can't see anything in the [XML::RSS::Parser documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aRSS%3a%3aParser) that mentions it working for Atom feeds.

Comment: It is valid. I just remove error check with is_error to make the example code shorter. on the documentation page you linked is "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" on the list

Comment: and I tested it with some others atom feeds

Comment: That's a the list of namespaces that the module recognises, not a list of file formats.